# Writing a 3D numpy array to files including its indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm very new to this so apologies but hopefully I have the syntax right so you understand my question!
I have a numpy array with shape (2,2,2)

```
array([[[ 1, 1],
        [ 2, 2]],

       [[ 3, 3],
        [ 4, 4]]])
```

how do I write it to a file so it list the indices and the array value
i.e.

```
0 0 0 1
1 0 0 3
0 1 0 2
1 1 0 4
0 0 1 1
1 0 1 3
0 1 1 2
1 1 1 4
```

thanks,
Ingrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.ndenumerate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html)

```
a = np.array([[[1, 1],
               [2, 2]],

              [[3, 3],
               [4, 4]]])

for items in np.ndenumerate(a):
    print(items)
```

Output

```
((0, 0, 0), 1)
((0, 0, 1), 1)
((0, 1, 0), 2)
((0, 1, 1), 2)
((1, 0, 0), 3)
((1, 0, 1), 3)
((1, 1, 0), 4)
((1, 1, 1), 4)
```

To remove the parentheses you can unpack everything

```
for indexes, value in np.ndenumerate(a):
    x,y,z = indexes
    print(x,y,z,value)
```

Output

```
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 2
0 1 1 2
1 0 0 3
1 0 1 3
1 1 0 4
1 1 1 4
```

To handle the file writing

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for indexes, value in np.ndenumerate(a):
        x,y,z = indexes
        f.write('{} {} {} {}\n'.format(x,y,z,value))
```

Comment: Would that work with the np.savetext to write it to a file? and if so can I strip out the brackets?

Comment: that all seems to work great except I get an errorTypeError: join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'seq'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way do this in NumPy, but you can do this using a combination of `numpy.unravel_index`, `numpy.dstack` and `numpy.savetxt`:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[[ 1, 1],
        [ 2, 2]],

       [[ 3, 3],
        [ 4, 4]]])
>>> a = np.dstack(np.unravel_index(np.arange(arr.size),
                                                   arr.shape) + (arr.ravel(),))
>>> np.savetxt('foo.txt', a[0,...], fmt='%d')
>>> !cat foo.txt
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 2
0 1 1 2
1 0 0 3
1 0 1 3
1 1 0 4
1 1 1 4
```